# How to separate backend and frontend in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, frontend, admin, laravel-5.4

I'm just learning Laravel, and was trying to separate admin and frontend. But I'm unable to separate. Can any one suggest how to do that?

Comment: `was trying to separate admin and fronted` What does it mean ?

Comment: Learn this document https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Comment: #Md. Abutaleb thank you for reference. but i have checked it.

Comment: #Sagar Gautam , that means " i tried  ".

Comment: This question can be closed as "unclear" or "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel's blade templating system to keep frontend code separate from the backend.

You can do things like this:

```
Hello, {{ $name }}.
```

..where $name is a variable passed from controller or your route.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade

Comment: Thanks for response, but i think its not the answer, i think my question is not clear.